# Facebook login not working without native app

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am integrating, facebook login, with the facebook app installed it works fine. but without the facebook app it isnt. I am getting this error

```
Cannot call LoginFragment with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
```

Here is the code

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays
                .asList("email", "public_profile"));

        // Receive Login Callback here
        LoginManager
                .getInstance()
                .registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                        if(mDialog != null)
                            mDialog.dismiss();

                        LogUtil.d(TAG, "Result == " + loginResult
                                .getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        // Application code
                                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                                    }
                                });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                        if (e instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

I tried all available Stack Overflow answers regarding the above error, so please don't paste any link without considering the exact problem. I don't have launch mode in the Facebook activity in the manifest and I also tried with standard launch mode, but nothing works.

Comment: May the activity which has Facebook Login button has singleInstance as launch mode.

Comment: Yes, the activity was single instance, whereas i was searching inside FacebookActivity Tag, Thanks